# How to set the default text of a text box from another form?

Tags: c#

I am currently developing a business program now when the program is launched it checks to see if the set-up has been completed through a non visible checkbox (I.E. If the user has done the set-up the check box will be checked if not it will be not checked)

I have tried googling this with no clear answer to how to do this.

So my question is, can I set the default text of a text box AND the default state of a checkbox through another form.

I.E. The user runs through the set-up and types the license key which then transfers to the main menu form where the program checks the license key. THEN when they finish the set-up it then checks a checkbox on the main menu so the set-up no longer shows up.

I already know how to transfer the text from form2 to form1 but I am just stuck on how to get it to set the default text to the text from form2.

This is the code from Form1:

```
 private void setup()
        {
            if(checkBox1.Checked == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR: No setup recorded. Entering Setup Now!");
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                Setup1 ds = new Setup1();
                ds.ShowDialog();
                textBox1.Text = ds.textBox1.Text;

            }

            if(checkBox1.Checked == true)
            {

            }
```

Form1:
http://prntscr.com/r87r4k

Set-Up Form(Form2):
http://prntscr.com/r87r9s

(Ignore the text boxes that state "Inactive" and "Active" that is for changing the license key status in the MYSQL Database.)

So in the end I want it so that the license key textbox (the empty text box in the first screenshot) will always open with the provided license key during setup.

Thank You,

Kadin

Answer (score 0):

Add a public method on your Setup1 called SetText(string text);

```
public void SetText(string text, bool isCompleted)
{
   TextBox1.Text = text;
   CheckBox1.Checked = isCompleted;
}
```

Then when you create your Setup1

```
Setup1 ds = new Setup1();'

// Set the text you want.
ds.SetText(myText, true);
```

Comment: ```public void SetText(string text, bool isCompleted)
{
   TextBox1.Text = text;
   CheckBox1.Text = isCompleted;
}
```
The Checkbox1.Text =isCompleted; line is throwing an error "cannot implictly convert type 'bool' to 'string'

[link](http://prntscr.com/r87v8s)

Comment: It is also saying on From1 that "isCompleted" does not exist in the current context http://prntscr.com/r87y0l

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry, I meant to say CheckBox1.Checked = isCompleted.

I changed the place where it had isCompleted to true, but it is your app, I don't know if it is completed or not.

Try that and maybe you are closer. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just override the default constructor for the form class and you will be set.

```
public MyForm(string text = “default text”)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Text = text;
}
```

EDIT: Create a new constructor and pass an optional parameter. If you dont’t set the value of 'text' then “default value” is going to be set.

Comment: But does that make it the default text everytime the user launches the program

Comment: Every time the component is created, yes.

Comment: But I cant get the form Setup1 to change the code in Form1, so that when the user completes the set-up everytime the program launch the license key will be in form1 which it is not be default it needs to be added by the user during set-up

Comment: So add it to the constructor with default value